# How to properly format a number String

Tags: java, string

I'm looking for an efficient way to have number `String`s properly formatted so it could be parsed to a `double` value.

Requirements:

- Ignore strings that don't only include digits, comma's (,) or dots (.);
- Reformat the number string so that it could be parsed to a double using
  `Double.parseDouble(numberString);`
- Throw a NumberFormatException when the input String isn't valid

Examples: 1.234.567,89 => 1234567.89; 5 => 5; 6.3 => 6.3; 5.23 => 5.23;...

To check if the `String` is a number, I'd like to user either regex or `NumberUtils.isNumber(numberString)`. Only problem with the latter one is that it has issues with strings like "123,45".

My current attempt (that feels pretty inefficient):

```
    LOGGER.debug("Normalizing price string: " + price);
    String str = price;

    if (str.contains(",") || str.contains(".")) {

        int pos = -1;
        if (str.contains(",")) pos = str.lastIndexOf(',');
        else if (str.contains(".")) pos = str.lastIndexOf(".");

        //Remove all the dots and commas first
        str = str.replaceAll("[,.]", "");

        if (!NumberUtils.isNumber(str) || !NumberUtils.isDigits(str)) {
            LOGGER.debug("String does not match expected pattern");
            throw new NumberFormatException();
        } else {
            //Add a dot back in

            if (str.length() <= 2) {
                StringBuilder first = new StringBuilder(str.substring(0, pos));
                first.append('.');
                String last = str.substring(pos);
                str = first + last;
            } else {
                StringBuilder first = new StringBuilder(str.substring(0, str.length() - 2));
                first.append('.');
                String last = str.substring(str.length() - 2);

                str = first + last;
            }
        }
    }

    LOGGER.debug("Normalised result: " + str);
    return str;`
```

How can this formatting be simplified, made more efficient, and correctly handle incorrect input?

**Applied solution**

```
    String str = price;
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfsDot = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    dfsDot.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfsComma = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    dfsComma.setDecimalSeparator(',');

    DecimalFormat dfDot = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00", dfsDot);
    DecimalFormat dfComma = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00", dfsComma);

    double d = 0;
    try {
        if (!str.contains(",") && !str.contains(".")) {
            return str;
        } else if (str.contains(",")) d = (Double) dfComma.parse(str);
        else if (str.contains(".")) d = (Double) dfDot.parse(str);
        str = "" + d;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        LOGGER.debug(str + " couldn't be cast to Double");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return price;
    }
```

Comment: String.format(...) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know `DecimalFormat` ?

```
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs =new DecimalFormatSymbols();
dfs.setDecimalSeparator('.');
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00",dfs);
double d = df.parse("123.45").doubleValue();
System.out.println(d);
```

It prints:

```
123.45
```

Comment: +1 for using `DecimalFormat`. However, this does not pass my test with certain values. It throws a `ClassCastException` for values: "123.45", "5",... (which is actually already fine to convert to a double I would think.